# Define a literal Javascript object so a property referenced directly calls a function and not its sub-ordinates

Tags: object, properties

I want to define a literal object in Javascript so that, for example:

```
myObject.foo()
```

returns an anonymous function, but

```
myObject.foo.bar()
```

returns a different anonymous function, and

```
myObject.foo.status
```

equals some string, etc.  Assume I'm starting with something like:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: {
        bar: function () { ... },
        status: "someString"
    }
}
```

How would I modify this accordingly?  Is it proper syntax to add a static reference like:

```
myObject.foo = function() { ... }
```

My guess is that, if valid, that would override the definition of **foo** entirely.  Is there an elegant way to achieve this?  I am creating a literal object that maps directly to a REST API URL so there is consistency between the URL and its object reference.

For example, if the relative URL for a particular API call is **myObject/foo** and another is **myObject/foo/bar**, then I would like the JS functions to be **myObject.foo()** and **myObject.foo.bar()**, respectively.

Comment: Assuming that you can't change the definition of `myObject`, this would be a duplicate of some other question -- let me find it :)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to find something, but I never came across it.